# Under what condition a normal space is compact hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We all know that every compact Hausdorff spaces are Normal can we talk about the converse? Even normal doesn't imply compact, take $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Exatly under the assumption that it is compact. Unfortunately, there is no other condition equivalent to compactness.

Comment: @Arthur: That's depends on the used convention, one can consider just the property of separating disjoint closed sets without points needed to be closed. In that case, a normal space is Hausdorff compact if and only if it is $T_1$ compact.

Comment: @Arthur: For those of us who use the sensible convention that makes the $T_k$ notation a genuine hierarchy, normal spaces are *not* automatically Hausdorff; $T_4$ spaces, which are normal and $T_1$, are automatically Hausdorff.